# Bootstrap nav pills padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hey there how i can change the padding of the pills (shown in picture)

[here my pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t6rE.jpg)

i want to fill the pills that i dont have the white "border"

didnt found that anywhere :-/

```html
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a  href="#">Startseite</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Unser Verein <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Vorstand</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Mitglieder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Unsere Kita</a></li>           
            <li><a href="#">Satzung</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Förderverein, warum?</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Please add your css in to the question.

Comment: its the classic bootstrap.css im searching for the element that i need to change.... should i post the whole css here :)

Comment: Uh...if you were just using the plain Bootstrap CSS for this, the navigation element would vertically filly the entire navbar. (ie. http://www.bootply.com/KeklJ9sajO) The problem probably lies in some custom, non-Bootstrap CSS - it would be good to include these additional styles that are affecting the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this class is `.navbar-left` or `.navbar-right` (depends on the class you use). To fix your padding issue just use in your custom CSS:

```
.navbar-right {
    padding: 0px;
}
```